# How do I use zsh's zle_highlight to highlight only "|"?

Tags: shell, zsh

I am currently using `zle_highlight` in zsh to highlight the entire command line. However, I also hope I could highlight "|" using a different more discerning style.

After googling for a while, I found no solution. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with just `zle_highlight`. It controls the appearance of UI elements (e.g. the region, or the incremental search text), not of normal text.

You can do this with the experimental [zsh syntax highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting) plugin. By default, it highlights keywords and command names, which may be enough. To highlight `|`, try something like

```
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_HIGHLIGHTERS+=(pattern)
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_PATTERNS+=('\|' fg=magenta,bold)
```

but note that this highlights all `|` characters everywhere, not just the ones that are pipes.